# Angular: Can't access data inside a component

Tags: angular, logic

I am building a widget that pulls in a weather API, then presents an image based on the data in said API. I'm having trouble accessing the data in the component. I can't quite see where I am going wrong.

The flow here: 
   On init, I subscribe to the data. I then (try) to assign that to another array (eval). Then, I call the evaluate method and execute the business logic.

The problem: I know that I am incorrect in the way I'm accessing eval[0] but if I move it to list[0], it won't compile. The data feed includes a list array that has the temp field in it.

Thank you!

```
import { WeatherRestService } from './../weatherRest.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Weather } from '../models/weather';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget',
  templateUrl: './widget.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget.component.css']
})
export class WidgetComponent implements OnInit {

  weather: Weather[];
  eval: Weather[] = [];
  light = 0;

  constructor(public rest:WeatherRestService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.index();
    this.evaluate();
  }

  index() {
    this.rest.index().subscribe(
      weather => { this.weather = weather; },
      err => {
        console.error('error retreiving properties');
        console.error(err);
      }
      );
    this.eval = this.weather; 
  }


  evaluate() {
    if (this.eval[0].list.main.temp < 20) {
      this.light = 1;
    } else if (this.eval[0].list.main.temp >= 20 && this.eval[0].list.main.temp < 50) {
      this.light = 2;
    } else if (this.eval[0].list.main.temp >= 50) {
      this.light = 3;
    }
  }

}
```

Here is an example of the JSON from the API:

```
{"cod":"200","message":0.008,"cnt":38,"list":[{"dt":1552024800,"main":{"temp":268.93,"temp_min":266.967,"temp_max":268.93,"pressure":1015.34,"sea_level":1015.34,"grnd_level":751.71,"humidity":72,"temp_kf":1.96},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.26,"deg":242.501},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2019-03-08 06:00:00"},{"dt":1552035600,"main":{"temp":267.23,"temp_min":265.757,"temp_max":267.23,"pressure":1015.09,"sea_level":1015.09,"grnd_level":750.66,"humidity":68,"temp_kf":1.47},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.32,"deg":226.502},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2019-03-08 09:00:00"},{"dt":1552424400,"main":{"temp":275.391,"temp_min":275.391,"temp_max":275.391,"pressure":1004,"sea_level":1004,"grnd_level":744.59,"humidity":83,"temp_kf":0},"weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],"clouds":{"all":88},"wind":{"speed":1.58,"deg":82.5016},"rain":{},"snow":{"3h":0.425},"sys":{"pod":"d"},"dt_txt":"2019-03-12 21:00:00"}],"city":{"id":5417598,"name":"Colorado Springs","coord":{"lat":38.8339,"lon":-104.8214},"country":"US"}}
```

Here, too, is the model I'm using:

```
export class Weather {
  cod: {
    city: {
    id: number,
    name: string
  };
  list: {
    main: {
      humidity: number,
      temp: number,
    }
  };
}

  constructor(i?: number, n?: string, h?: number, t?: number) {
    this.cod.city.id = i;
    this.cod.city.name = n;
    this.cod.list.main.humidity = h;
    this.cod.list.main.temp = t;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data of the structure that the service gives you.

Comment: {"cod":"200","message":0.008,"cnt":38,"list":[{"dt":1552024800,"main":{"temp":268.93,"temp_min":266.967,"temp_max":268.93,"pressure":1015.34,"sea_level":1015.34,"grnd_level":751.71,"humidity":72,"temp_kf":1.96},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"clouds":{"all":0},"wind":{"speed":2.26,"deg":242.501},"sys":{"pod":"n"},"dt_txt":"2019-03-08 06:00:00"}, .... 

"city":{"id":5417598,"name":"Colorado Springs","coord":{"lat":38.8339,"lon":-104.8214},"country":"US"}}

Comment: The elipses on the second to last light is just repeating segments of the same structure just forward forecasts.

Comment: That may not be helpful. If there are extra fields in object, please remove it and post a `valid` JSON in the question.

Comment: I will try right now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has several problems related asynchronious data fetching:

- `this.eval = this.weather;` is dependent on subscription, so you need to assign it inside of `subscribe`
- the method `evaluate` is dependant on `this.eval`

You need to put all operations that depend on `this.rest.index` inside of `subscribe` to it:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.index();
}

index() {
  this.rest.index().subscribe(
    weather => { 
      this.weather = weather;
      this.eval = this.weather;  
      this.evaluate();
    },
    err => {
      console.error('error retreiving properties');
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is populating the data into eval now. I suspected it was async related but didn't know how to overcome that. 

May I ask, how do I then access the data in this.eval? I think I am missing something in the JSON access (e.g., this.eval[0].list.main.temp doesn't work). 

I can access in the HTML just not in the .ts

Comment: @RobThompson the problem you cannot access `this.eval[0].list.main.temp` is that `this.eval` is an object, not an array. Try it this way: `this.eval.list[0].main.temp`

Comment: @RobThompson feel free to accept/upvote the answer if it helped)

Comment: I need four more rep and I sure will! 

It worked for a moment but now I'm getting a compilation error: 

ERROR in src/app/weatherRest.ts(5,1): error TS2582: Cannot find name 'describe'. 
src/app/weatherRest.ts(6,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
src/app/weatherRest.ts(8,3): error TS2582: Cannot find name 'it'. 
src/app/weatherRest.ts(10,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i @types/jest` or `npm i @types/mocha`.

Comment: @RobThompson I guess you need to add inside your `tsconfig.json` settings `"types": ["jest"]`, like so: `"compilerOptions": { "types": ["jest"] }`

Comment: Thank you; I tried that but it's still not compiling. May I ask, what change prompted the need to insert the code into the tsconfig.json? I.e., what did I do that broke it?

Comment: Update: so it DOES run but also presents compilation errors (interesting). Also, it won't let me build the production package due to the compilation errors.

Comment: @RobThompson the error `Cannot find name 'describe'. src/app/weatherRest.ts(6,3): ` relates to `types` for `jest`, so if you have in your `tsconfig.json` an empty array for types: `"compilerOptions": { "types": [] }`, there'll be also an error like this.

Comment: Thank you - I currently have "jest" in the types... 

It's no longer loading, either. :/

Answer (score -1):

You could check the sample blew. we could access this.eval in the complete callback function. We must use Non-blocking style for this kind of stuff, the code will not be blocked and wait. We could not access this.eval like we do in sychronize style.

```
myObservable.subscribe(
  x => console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x),
  err => console.error('Observer got an error: ' + err),
  **() => console.log('Observer got a complete notification')**
);
```